# How to invoke msbuild default target from powershell script?

Tags: msbuild, powershell-3.0

Can anyone help me to know how can we invoke msbuild default target from a Powershell script?

msbuild script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="TestMethod">
   <Target Name="TestMethod">
      <Message Text="Test Method Invoke Finished..." Importance="high"/>
   </Target>
</Project>
```

I want to invoke the target `TestMethod` from a Powershell script.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: If you do `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /?` you'll see that msbuild has a `target` switch. Have you tried `/target:TestMethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to invoke the msbuild default target (i.e. target =TestMethod) from a powershell script. Please find the example below :

Powershell Script:

## MSBUILD Path

$msbuildexe = (get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0").MSBuildToolsPath + 'msbuild.exe'

#### Function to Invoke TestMethod

function Invoke-TestMethodFromPowershell([string]$testProjFile)
{
  echo "Calling msbuild Started ..."
  &$msbuildexe $testProjFile
  echo "Calling msbuild Completed ..."
}

Invoke-VeracodeScanSubmissionProcess("C:\Temp\HelloWorldTest\TestBuild.proj");

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
msbuild /path/to/projectfile
```

If you do not specify a target, msbuild automatically picks the `DefaultTargets`. Or if that is not available, it calls the first one encountered.

Comment: I am trying to invoke the target from the powershell script not from the cmd prompt.

Comment: well that is merely a syntax difference, you still have to get the arguments correct.. As in your own answer :]